# Displaying API data on button click

Tags: javascript, html, api

I would like to make different news feed and trigger them on click. Currently i have different subpage on my website and when I click there it redirects me on another page, API shows the information. It looks like this.
Any ideas how i can setup same way but to trigger api on button without redirecting on another page. Ideal - I want to have a container which gonna keep different news feed and trigger different ones on click.
Sorry for lame question, novice in API's.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

let url = "https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=bitcoin&from=2020-04-01&to=2020-04-20&apiKey=APIKEY";
$.ajax({
  url:url, 
  method: "GET", 
  dataType: "Json",

  beforeSend: function(){
    $(".progress").show();
  },

  complete: function(){
    $(".progress").hide();
  },

  success: function(news){
    let output = "";
    let latestNews = news.articles;
    for(var i in latestNews) {
      output +=`
        <div class="col">
          <div class="card-content">
          <h5><a href="${latestNews[i].url}">${latestNews[i].title}</a></h5>
          </div>
          </div>
          <div class="published">
          <h6>${latestNews[i].publishedAt}</h6>
          </div>
          <div class"card-reveal">
          <p>${latestNews[i].description}</p>
        </div>
      `;
    }
    if(output !== ""){
      $("#newsResults").html(output);
    }

  },

  error: function(){
    $("#newsResults").html("Some error occured");
  }
})
```

});

Answer (score 0):

You can add a listener to a button click using jQuery like so:

```
// Suppose your button has id='target'
$( "#target" ).click(function() {
  your api call here
});
```

https://api.jquery.com/click/